# Reading a struct containing character array

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, char, binaryreader

I have the following struct:

```
unsafe struct Locomotive
{
    public fixed char locotype[6];
    public int roadno,HP;
}
```

I have successfully written this to a binary file. Here's the code:

```
Locomotive l1 = new Locomotive();
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    l1.locotype[i] = textBox1.Text[i];
}
l1.roadno = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
l1.HP = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Ruchir Sharma\Desktop\Locodata.bin", FileMode.Append));
IntPtr ip = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(l1));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(l1, ip, true);
Byte[] b1 = new Byte[Marshal.SizeOf(l1)];
Marshal.Copy(ip, b1, 0, b1.Length - 1);
bw.Write(b1);
MessageBox.Show("Data written successfully");
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ip);
bw.Close();
```

Now, while reading this struct, the character array i.e locotype[6] is giving me a problem. I tried the method BinaryReader.ReadChars(), but it didn't worked for me. Please help me on reading this struct.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are manually serializing it?

Comment: Define "didn't work" - what happened?

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras No specific reason Sir. I read that one can also serialize using BinaryFormatter.Serialize, but that's only for classes. I'm using a struct...

Comment: @Ruchir no, not just for classes. It might not love fixed buffers, though

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm trying to read the file as follows:
 BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Ruchir Sharma\Desktop\Locodata.bin",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read));
br.ReadChars(6)); 
br.ReadInt32();
br.ReadInt32();
but the ReadChars method is not reading my array "locotype" correctly...

Comment: @Ruchir if you want to read it like that, you should write it like that too...

Answer (score 0):

Your "read" code should be the reverse of your "write" code. You didn't write it with WriteChars, so don't use ReadChars to read it. You should use ReadBytes then Marshal.Copy and PtrToStructure.

Frankly, though, this level of "unsafe" (fixed buffers in structs, Marshal, etc) is very rare and specialized - I worry you might be over-engineering this.

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna use ReadBytes now. Thanks for your answer. In fact, thanks everyone :)